# WPF AutoCompleteBox multiple fields

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF autocompletebox and it is populated with a list of Organization_Names queried from database. Now I want to get the Organization_ID when a user selects an organization name from the autocompletebox dropdown. I can query the database again to get the ID based on the selected Organization_Name, but I think there got be a better way to do. How to add an invisible column in the dropdown so it won't be displayed but i can get its value? I am pretty new to WPF. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks, 
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind the autocomplete box to an object.

```
class MyClass
{
    public int Organization_ID{ get; set; }
    public string Organization_Names{ get; set; }
}

<controls:AutoCompleteBox x:Name="autoCompleteBox1"    
      SelectionChanged="autoCompleteBox1_SelectionChanged"      
      FilterMode="Contains"              
      IsTextCompletionEnabled="True">
    <controls:AutoCompleteBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Organization_Names}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </controls:AutoCompleteBox.ItemTemplate>
</controls:AutoCompleteBox>

private void autoCompleteBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   MessageBox.Show(((MyClass)autoCompleteBox1.SelectedItem).Organization_ID);
}
```

Comment: appreciate your quick response. how can I bind a query result (date table with 2 columns) to the autocompletebox? Thanks for your further explanation.

Comment: You would need to loop through your datatable and add the results to a list `List<MyClass> list = new List<MyClass>();`  and then use the list as the autocomplete box itemsource: `autoCompleteBox1.ItemSource = list;`

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was able to populate the autocomplete box from a datatable. However, when I make a selection from the dropdown, it shows me the namespace.class. How to let it show the organization_name? thanks.

Comment: overriding the ToString() method of my class did the trick. thanks for your help.